# WVD Mixed AD Environment AAD and Local AD

Tags: azure-active-directory

Most of my customers have a split AD environment, they are logging into their machine via their local AD e.g. user1@domain1.net and accessing O365 with user1@fire.domain2.gov the UPNs do not match.  The Azure tenant and Azure AD exist on the O365 UPN.

Only workaround we have found is to add the UPN fire.domain2.gov to the local AD object or add the O365 account to the local domain.  Any other workarounds that might work and has anyone else ran into this?

Comment: Have you tried using [Alternate-Login-Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/configuring-alternate-login-id)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm told Alternate login ID will not work. No, AltID is used with ADFS. There is no ADFS in La County anymore (Dan Jorenby)

We are trying to setup a deployment for an government entity in LA county where they already have a local Ad and AAD accounts for Office 365, but no sync is set between them. Do you have any suggestion on how he can bind them together to be able to use them in WVD?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access your on-premises and Azure resources with single identity, you need to sync your user's objects from on-premises active directory to Azure Active directory via azure ad connect.
You need to create a custom domain in Azure in order to sync your user objects from on-premises to Azure.
Ex: you can configure a custom domain for fire.domain2.gov in azure. You can add the same domain name in on-premises by adding additional UPN suffix in Active directory domain and trust.
In order to get the detailed information check [Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/prepare-a-non-routable-domain-for-directory-synchronization)